# Solutions to ODE/SDE with singular coefficients $dX_t = -X_t/t \, dt + g\,dW_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, singularity-theory

I encountered a question regarding the solutions to SDEs with singular drifts. I searched the literature but had a hard time figuring out the intuition behind these analytic results assuming different types of regularity. I am considering the following simple example:

$$dX_t = -\frac{X_t}{t} \, dt + g \, dW_t$$

When $g = 0$, it is an ODE, and we can find a family of solutions to this ODE: $X_t = c/t$, which makes sense only for $t>0$ except for the trivial solution $X_t = 0$ (Are these all the possible solutions? Is there any general theory on this?)

When $g = 1$, it is an SDE, and we can find the following family of solutions
$$X_t =\frac{1}{t} \left(\int_0^t s \, dW_s +c\right).$$
When $c=0$, the above solution is well-defined for all $t$. Is this the only well-defined solution at $t=0$, and in which sense is it a solution?

As indicated by the above example, SDEs seem to provide a broader class of nontrivial solutions than ODEs. I would appreciate any reference regarding this topic. Thanks!

Comment: it seems the best one can do is start from $t_{0}>0$ because indeed for initial $t_{0}=0$ even the ODE has issues and that is usually a sign for problems for the SDE (although not always eg. Yamada-Watanabe gives existence to some SDEs that are singular see Revuz-Yor).

Comment: Noise is additive so solutions make sense pathwise. So you can get any solution by starting somewhere at time $1$ and then solving backwards to time $0$, which shows that there aren't any solutions other than the ones you found.

Comment: @MartinHairer Thank you! I tried to formulate the backward SDE, which gives me the solution $$X_t = \frac{1}{t}\mathbb{E}[X_1 | \mathcal{F}_t]$$ I don't know how to proceed from here to obtain the final solution formula. I tried an alternative way: first show the solution of the SDE is a Gaussian process. Then derive the ODEs for mean and covariance and figure out all the solutions to the ODEs

Comment: @ThomasKojar Yes I agree! Numerically I start at $t_0 = \epsilon$, set $x_{t_0} = 0$, and use Euler-Maruyama; this gives a good approximation of the non-singular solution $$X_t = \frac{1}{t}\int_0^t s dW_s$$

Comment: @Yifan My commend has nothing to do with backwards SDEs. It is just about viewing this as a random ODE and solving it backwards in time, which is not the same thing. The reason you can do this is that the noise is additive so there's no stochastic integral involved.

Comment: @MartinHairer I see! For pathwise defined solutions, the equation $d(tX_t) = gt dW_t$ holds pathwise, then using this equation all solutions can be obtained by integration. This makes sense!